# RavenDB index with map reduce distinct

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have a slightly complex index that I need over a RavenDB document

given this document definition like:

```
public class PriceDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PriceId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PricingDate { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }    
}
```

I need to get all the products for a given `productId` (I can do that when I query)
that are unique by `PricingDate` (latest) and `Source`

So given the following data:

```
var priceDocument = new PriceDocument  {
    Price = 1m,
    Id = productId + "/1",
    PricingDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1, 8, 0, 0),
    PriceId = productId,
    Source = "Bloomberg",
    Version = 1   
};

var priceDocument1 = new PriceDocument {
    Price = 1m,
    Id = productId + "/2",
    PricingDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1,9,0,0),
    PriceId = productId,
    Source = "Bloomberg", 
    Version = 1
};
```

I should get as a result  priceDocument1, since its latest.

So far I have an index defined like this:

```
Map = docs => 
    from priceDocument in docs
    select new {
        PricingDate = priceDocument.PricingDate, 
        PricingSource = priceDocument.Source,
        Price = priceDocument.Price,
        PriceId = priceDocument.PriceId
    };

Reduce = results => 
    from result in results
    group result by new { result.PricingDate, result.Source } into price
    select new {
        PricingDate = price.Max(p => price.Key.PricingDate),
        PricingSource = price.Key.Source,
    };
```

But it doesnt work at run time, I'm getting an `AbstractIndexingExecuter||8||Failed to index documents for index (my index name)`

I've recreated this sample in a separate project and I can see that in stats in Raven Studio that I get the error:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTimeOffset' to 'int'* changed the `DateTime?` to `DateTime`

And no luck.

I switched from using the date to use the I can rely on it incrementing so now the index looks like this:

```
Map = docs => 
    from priceDocument in docs
    select new {
        PricingDate = priceDocument.PricingDate,
        PricingSource = priceDocument.Source,
        ProductId = priceDocument.ProductId,
        ProductVersion = priceDocument.Version
    };

Reduce = results => 
    from result in results
    group result by new {
        result.PriceId,
        result.PricingDate,
        result.Source,
        result.Version
    } into price
    select new {
        PricingDate = price.Key.PricingDate,
        PricingSource = price.Key,
        ProductVersion = price.Max(p=> price.Key.Version)
    };
```

Now that throws no errors, however it also gives no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should probably be this:

```
   PricingDate = price.Max(p => (DateTimeOffset)price.Key.PricingDate)
```

But what you want doesn't require a map reduce index. You can get that by just using:

```
session.Query<PriceDocument>()
       .Where(x=>x.ProduceId == prodId)
       .OrderByDescending(x=>x.PriceDate)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

The reason your Map/Reduce index doesn't work is that you have different outputs for the map & reduce functions.

Comment: Hi Ayende: Thanks for the answer, the thing is that it must be unique by PriceDate and by PricingSource (ie I can have 2 rows with the same date as long as the source is different)  and select the one where the version ( or date) is the highest

Comment: This wasnt the whole answer however, @ayende responded the question in the raven discussion group https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ravendb/B9HCmi32YWw/discussion and the solution is here https://gist.github.com/1186051

Answer (score 3):

Trying changing this line in the Reduce part of the index, from

```
PricingDate = price.Max(p => price.Key.PricingDate)
```

to

```
PricingDate = price.Max(p => (int)price.Key.PricingDate)
```

Comment: Thanks I ve tryed that and now the result is no errors but no results either